# Unable to update the field when it is in Edit mode

Tags: trigger

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Trigger:**

```
trigger Triggertovalidate on GEN_Parameter__c (BEFORE INSERT,BEFORE UPDATE)
{
    LIST<GEN_Parameter__c> li = [select id,Country__c from GEN_Parameter__c where id != null]; 
    for(GEN_Parameter__c c :trigger.new)
    {
     if(c.Country__c != null){
      for(GEN_Parameter__c existrecord :li)
      {
          if(existrecord.Country__c == c.Country__c ){
          c.Country__c.addError('Country is already used please select another one.');
          }
      }
     }
    }

}
```

**Problem:**
I am checking unique value for Country Pick list, while inserting and updating the record.

This is working fine while inserting a record.
When i am updating the record , I am unable to update the record for the same country. Its showing Trigger error country already exist.

My Goal is not to create duplicate record for  country while insert or update.But I am not able to update my original(unique) record itself.

Please help to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: while i am updating my original record, its check box and values. i am getting error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Salesforcesmarty 's answer is almost correct. You simply need to change the condition line into:

```
if(trigger.isInsert || (trigger.isUpdate && existrecord.Id != c.Id))
```

And this will work for you.

Comment: I din't understand your logic of comparing the ids instead of Country values?

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty I finally understand your logic now. For my implementation, I simply made sure the obj to compare is not the same one as the current one in trigger. In most cases, your code will work. But let's consider the edge scenario you bulk changed two obj's country__c at the same execution context by simply switching the two values. It will fail in your code.

Comment: @Salesforcesmarty after one more thought... That scenario will fail both of ours' code... The best way is to restrict the original set.. However, this is very edge case.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will throw error, even though you are not updating any country field on update.

Update your code with this:

```
trigger Triggertovalidate on GEN_Parameter__c (BEFORE INSERT,BEFORE UPDATE)
{
    Set<String> countries = new Set<String>();
    for(GEN_Parameter__c country : [select id,Country__c from GEN_Parameter__c where id != null]);
        countries.add(country.country__c);

    for(GEN_Parameter__c c :trigger.new){
        if(c.Country__c != null){
            if(trigger.isInsert || (trigger.isUpdate && trigger.OldMap.get(c.id).Country__c != c.Country__c)){
                if(countries.contains(c.Country__c)){
                    c.Country__c.addError('Country is already used please select another one.');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for updating original record its working, when i select duplicate country its creating new record with duplicate country.

Comment: Try this updated optimised code.